# Discord bot doesn't send an image

Tags: c#, discord.net

I want my bot to send an image from given url with caption got from String(), but with SendFileAsync() it totally doesn't work. Is there another method for sending images from internet or I just screwed up something in here?

```
public class Task : ModuleBase
        {
            public Task()
            {
                Thread.Sleep(6000);
                IReadOnlyCollection<SocketGuild> guilds = CommandHandler._discord.Guilds;
                foreach (var guild in guilds)
                {
                    JobManager.AddJob(() => CommandHandler._discord.GetGuild(guild.Id).DefaultChannel.SendFileAsync("HERE_GOES_URL", String()), (s) => s.ToRunEvery(5).Seconds());
                }
            }
        }
        static void Initializer()
        {
            JobManager.Initialize(new MyRegistry());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `SendFileAsync`, you need to have the file locally.
If you want to send a URL without downloading, just use `SendMessageAsync`. Discord will preview the image from the URL (unless the user disabled that manually).

Otherwise, this would help:

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
...
byte[] buffer = (new WebClient().DownloadData("myurl"));
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
   await SendFileAsync(ms, ...);
}
```

Wrapping this to a function is what I'd recommend.

If you are still convinced about not dealing with downloads, check out `EmbedBuilder`.

**Notes not related to your question**

- You shouldn't send messages to guilds in a loop, which will definitely cause issues for you, such as rate-limits.
- You should await async functions. See [How and when to use ‘async’ and ‘await’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await) for more information.